# Extract date and time from ID

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I have ID field which contains the value `201503061500389804`. The timestamp is given in this ID. The format of the ID value is as follows: yyyyMMddhhmmss.
For e.g 201503061500389804 = 2015-03-06 15:00:38. The last 4 digits are not needed. I want to extract the date and time from ID and save it in new column say EVENT_DATE. But did not find any way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ID represents a timestamp you could include the last four digits as fractional seconds - if that is what they represent - using `to_timestamp()` instead of `to_date()`:

```
select to_timestamp('201503061500389804',
  'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF4') as event_timestamp
from dual;

EVENT_TIMESTAMP           
--------------------------
2015-03-06 15:00:38.980400
```

Or you could cast that to a date if you don't want o preserve the fractional seconds:

```
select cast(to_timestamp('201503061500389804',
  'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF4') as date) as event_date
from dual;

EVENT_DATE         
-------------------
2015-03-06 15:00:38
```

Or trim off the last four digits and use `to_date()`:

```
select to_date(substr('201503061500389804', 1, 14),
  'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as event_date
from dual;

EVENT_DATE         
-------------------
2015-03-06 15:00:38
```

You said you want to save it in a new column; if you're on 11g or higher you can do this with a virtual column:

```
alter table your_table add event_date date generated always as
  (to_date(substr(to_char(id), 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'));
```

or

```
alter table your_table add event_date date generated always as
  (cast(to_timestamp(to_char(id), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF4') as date));
```

Then you don't have to worry about setting the value as part of your insert or via a trigger, it'll just be there automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_date()`.  I think this is the format string:

```
select to_date(substr(id, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```